# What is the difference between Limit and BatchSize in MongoCursor?

Tags: .net, mongodb

The MongoDB cursor object provides a `BatchSize` property *and* and `Limit` property but I can't seem to find any definitive information that properly clarifies the difference between the two.

I'm using the .Net driver, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Limit is the total number of results you want. If your query would return one thousand documents but you only want 5 you can use Limit to limit the size of the total result.

BatchSize is the number of results that should be returned in each batch. If your result set for a query is large MongoDB isn't going to return all the results in one batch. It will return a subset of the total result, then the cursor will send a getMore message to the server when it needs the next batch of results.

Comment: Ok, so setting BatchSize causes the cursor to internally page through the results in order to satisfy the total number of documents to return as dictated by limit?

Comment: No. Let's say you have a query that returns 1000 small documents. The first time you call cursor.next() the cursor will get it's first batch of documents from the server. By default this will be 101 documents. If instead you set BatchSize to 5 the first batch will only be 5 documents, then every time the cursor runs out of documents it will get 5 more from the server until the entire result set has been returned.

Comment: This may be the source of my confusion. The MongoDB .Net driver doesn't have a Next() method.

Comment: MongoCursor has a GetEnumerator method. The enumerator has a MoveNext method. Normally you don't need to use low level enumerator methods, you just consume the cursor in a foreach loop.

Answer (score 7):

I got this from the MongoDB documentation:

> [batchSize] limits the number of elements returned in one batch. A cursor typically fetches a batch of result objects and stores them locally. If batchSize is positive, it represents the size of each batch of objects retrieved. It can be adjusted to optimize performance and limit data transfer. If batchSize is negative, it will limit of number objects returned, that fit within the max batch size limit (usually 4MB), and cursor will be closed. For example if batchSize is -10, then the server will return a maximum of 10 documents and as many as can fit in 4MB, then close the cursor. **Note that this feature is different from limit() in that documents must fit within a maximum size, and it removes the need to send a request to close the cursor server-side.** The batch size can be changed even after a cursor is iterated, in which case the setting will apply on the next batch retrieval.

Here's a link to the glossary of terms where this came from: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#batchSize(int)

Comment: I did see that but it didn't really clarify what it meant by batching, asin, do I need to advance the batch? Is it something done internally? What's this about closing the cursor server-side?

Comment: Negative batchSize doesn't work for mongocsharpdriver v1.8.1. It will fail with "System.ArgumentException: BatchSize cannot be negative.
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCursor`1.SetBatchSize(Int32 batchSize)"